# Script Exception while parsing an java.object to ScriptEngine

Tags: java, json

What i'm trying to do is to parse in browser address bar a json object through java code. The JSON object i want to to obtain should be:

```
{idUtente : "idUtente"}
```

So i implemented this code

```
public void inviaMailConferma(Utente utente) throws Exception {

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(utente.getEmail());
    message.setSubject("Conferma registrazione a Portfolio Online");
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String idUtente = utente.getUsername();
    Object eval = engine.eval("print(encodeURIComponent(idUtente))");
    message.setText("Ciao " + utente.getUsername() + "! Per registrarsi al sito, cliccare il seguente link: " + ip.getHostAddress() + ":8084/VenditaGioielli/confermaRegistrazione?data=" + eval.toString());
    mailSender.send(message);

}
```

when i run engine.eval, i'm gettin this Exception

```
ex = (javax.script.ScriptException) javax.script.ScriptException:
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "idUtente" is not
defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

I don't know how to parse a java Object to engine.val!

EDIT

now i came to this code

```
 ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 String idUtente = utente.getUsername();
 engine.put("idUtente", idUtente);
 Object eval = engine.eval("print(encodeURIComponent(idUtente))");
```

but engine.eval returns null!

EDIT

now i come to this code

```
 ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 ScriptContext scriptContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
 Bindings binding = scriptContext.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
 String idUtente = utente.getUsername();
 engine.put("idUtente", idUtente);
 Object eval = engine.eval("print(encodeURIComponent(idUtente))", binding);
```

and i have the following exception:

```
"sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "idUtente" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1)"
```

Comment: Is `{idUtente : idUtente}` actually valid JSON in the first place? Try `{idUtente : "idUtente"}` for example.

Comment: @HannoBinder, i edited the question, it was a writing error!

Comment: of course it returns null... you are just printing the encoded string.

Comment: @markusw, so wath i have to do?

Comment: you could try to define a function in the script which returns the desired value and invoke that function with `Invocable`

Comment: tomorrow i'll try the new code and the invocable metod!

Comment: i made some change to the code, but now i have another excetion!

Answer (score 0):

The engine has it's own context and does not know what `idUtente` is. Just put it into the context via `engine.put("idUtente", idUtente)`. That should work.

I wrote a blog post about ScriptEngine and bindings especially: http://wondee.info/2013/10/30/the-scriptengine-bindings/

Comment: did you put it in the context before you eval the script?

Comment: now i haven't here my laptop, so i can't work. i re-edited the post whit a new code, the day after Tomorrow i'll try.

Comment: i was able to put in the context, but now i have another exception!

Comment: i was able to put in the context, but now i have another excetion!

Comment: delete this getBindings line and don't pass a bindings argument. You put the variable in the bindings of the engine and than override it with passing the old bindings to the eval call

Comment: in this way the context is not put in, in fact eval is null.